# Facebook connect - login and grant permission at the same time

Tags: facebook, fbml

I've been able to get my app to login and grant permissions after, but I woul dnow like to do it at the same time

The login button that is being generated is using the following code

```
<fb:login-button perms="publish_stream"></fb:login-button>
```

Any ideas why its not picking up on the perms?

Thanks,
Ian

Answer (score 0):

There is a fbml tag also for that, try this:

[`fb:prompt-permission`](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Fb:prompt-permission)

**Example:**

```
<fb:prompt-permission perms="email">
  Would you like to receive email from our application?
</fb:prompt-permission>
```

Comment: I seem to be only table to use that tag once logged in, I would like to do the login and permission granting at the same time.